# How to remove borders from selected cells of a table

Tags: tables

I was preparing a question paper where I have to insert the following question. How to print the table? My main point of the query is how to remove the borders from the boundary cells?

[image]

Comment: I probably wouldn't do this a a table, but rather make it as a tikz graphics, much easier to control.

Comment: By ‘removing the border’, you mean obtaining a table similar to the table in the image?

Comment: Please, can you add your minimal working example?

Comment: @Sebastiano I have not done anything in Tex. This table is done in MS Word.

Comment: @Bernard Yes. Exact similar.

Comment: @daleif Can you please give me a MWE? I am quite new in Latex, sadly do not have much idea about it.

Comment: @SubhajitPaul sorry, then it is a _do it for me_ question, which I do not have time for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach using `\multicolumn` and `\cline` to add lines in a table without vertical rules (`\begin{tabular}{llll}`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{llll}
    & $D_{1}$ & $D_{2}$ & $a_{i}$ \\
    \cline{2-3}
    $O_{2}$ & \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{12} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{13} & 14 \\
    \cline{2-3}
    $O_{3}$ & \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{15} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{16} & 17 \\
    \cline{2-3}
    $b_{j}$ & 21 & 22 & \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Even easier is maybe starting with a table with vertical rules (`\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l}`) and  removing the borders only for the cells on the edges. 
The result is the same:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l}
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{$D_{1}$} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{$D_{2}$} & $a_{i}$ \\
    \cline{2-3}
    $O_{2}$ & 12 & 13 & 14 \\
    \cline{2-3}
    $O_{3}$ & 15 & 16 & 17 \\
    \cline{2-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{$b_{j}$} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{21} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{22} & \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: LaTeX]

Answer (score 3):

This is very simple with the `blkarray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}

    \[ \setlength{\BAextrarowheight}{2pt}
     \begin{blockarray}{*{6}{c}}%
     & D₁ & D₂ & D₃ & D₄ & a_i \\
     \BAhhline{~|---|-~}
    \begin{block}{c|*{4}{c|}c}
    O₁ & 23 & 27 & 16 & 18 & 30 \\
     \BAhhline{~|----|~}
     O₂ & 12 & 17 & 20 & 51 & 40 \\
     \BAhhline{~|----|~}
    O₃ & 22 & 28 & 12 & 32 & 53 \\
     \end{block*}
     \BAhhline{~|----|~}
     b_j & 22 & 35 & 25 & 41
   \end{blockarray} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]